# C++ Template function with is_same type_trait not working for type T=std::string

Tags: c++11, templates

I have implemented a simple Xerces-c based C++ library for parsing and reading data items from XML config files. I provide facility to convert data types read into int, long, double, bool, float and string.

All items work fine except std::string where any conversion is not needed. I would simply like to compare using traits and return but it does not work. is_same works only for built in types ?

```
template<typename T> T CppXMLConfigReader::getTypeVal(const std::string& key, const T& defaultVal) const
{
    T returnVal = defaultVal;
    auto iter = m_configMapItems.find(key.c_str());
    if(iter != m_configMapItems.end())
    {
        try
        {
            if(is_same<T,int>::value)
                returnVal = stoi(iter->second);
            if(is_same<T,float>::value)
                returnVal = stof(iter->second);
            if(is_same<T,long>::value)
                returnVal = stol(iter->second);
            if(is_same<T,double>::value)
                returnVal = stod(iter->second);
            if(is_same<T,bool>::value)
            {
                if(iter->second == "true" || iter->second == "1")
                    returnVal=true;
                else
                    returnVal=false;
            }
            if(is_same<T,string>::value)   // Error is from here.
                returnVal = iter->second;  // Error is from here.
        }
        catch(const invalid_argument& e)
        {
            cout << "Exception happened while converting " << iter->second << " Into rqequired type. Please investigate." << endl;
        }
    }
    return(returnVal);
}
```

Comment: How are you calling `getTypeVal`? You are probably passing something as a second parameter - e.g. a string literal - whose type is not in fact `std::string`.

Comment: second type is of T which serves as default value for fallback in case config is not stored. so in case it is string then second parameter is string and iter->second is also a string so should work ?

Comment: Unless explicitly specified, `T` is deduced from the type of the second argument. So if second argument is not of type `std::string`, then `T` is also not `std::string`. So, again, show how you call `getTypeVal` in that case where it doesn't work as you expect.

Comment: The code is here below.                                                                  string CppXMLConfigReader::getStringValue(const string& key, const string& defaultVal) const
{
    string returnVal = getTypeVal<string>(key, defaultVal);
    return(returnVal);
}

Comment: You only use string in is_same, but use std::string elsewhere?

Comment: Actually, upon closer inspection, this shouldn't compile for pretty much any type. You see, all your `if (is_same` checks are resolved at run time. Every assignment must still be syntactically valid at compile time - but you can't assign an int to a string, or a string to an int. With sufficiently modern compiler, you could use [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If). But if you have to work with C++11 (as per the tag), you need to employ some template metaprogramming technique, e.g. a traits class with specializations for every type.

Comment: Igor , you are right. perhaps my approach is wrong ...I should use metaprogramming to selectively expand for each required type.